# Bypassing LCK_M_SCH_S lock when requesting partition information

Tags: sql-server

I have code to query partition data.
But when the database creates an index, my query does not work because of the LCK_M_SCH_S lock, although I use the NOLOCK hint for all tables.
Is there any way around this lock?

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
        , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) as TableschemaName
        , OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
        , p.index_id AS 'IndexId'
        , CASE WHEN p.index_id = 0 THEN 'HEAP'
                ELSE i.name
            END AS 'IndexName'
        , p.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
        , prv_left.value AS LowerBoundary
        , prv_right.value AS UpperBoundary
        , ps.name as PartitionScheme
        , pf.name as PartitionFunction
        , c.name AS [Partitioning Column]
        , TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) AS [Column Type]
        , CASE WHEN fg.name IS NULL THEN ds.name
                ELSE fg.name
            END AS 'FileGroupName'
        , CAST(p.used_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS UsedPagesMB
        , CAST(p.in_row_data_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS DataPagesMB
        , CAST(p.reserved_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS ReservedPagesMB
        , CASE WHEN p.index_id IN (0,1) THEN p.row_count
                ELSE 0
            END AS RowsQuantity
        ,CASE WHEN p.index_id IN (0,1) THEN 'data'
                ELSE 'index'
            END AS Type
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN sys.indexes i WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.OBJECT_ID = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    JOIN sys.data_spaces ds WITH (NOLOCK) ON ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_functions pf WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces dds WITH (NOLOCK) ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
                                            AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
    LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg WITH (NOLOCK)   ON fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv_right WITH (NOLOCK) ON prv_right.function_id = ps.function_id
                                                AND prv_right.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv_left WITH (NOLOCK) ON prv_left.function_id = ps.function_id
                                                AND prv_left.boundary_id = p.partition_number - 1
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOLOCK) ON ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id]   
                                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id   
                                AND ic.partition_ordinal >= 1 
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.OBJECT_ID = c.[object_id]   
                            AND ic.column_id = c.column_id  
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(p.OBJECT_ID, 'ISMSSHipped') = 0
        AND p.index_id IN (0,1) 
        AND ps.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: As far as I know, schema stability locks can not be bypassed

Comment: How often are you creating indexes that this is a problem?

Comment: indexes creating all the time, because we switching old data for new with switch partition